# Dynamic default open page in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my data in sheet "Sheet1"

```
ID  Jan-13  Feb-13  Mar-13  Apr-13  Apr-13  May-13  Jun-13  Jul-13  Aug-13  Sep-13
A1  12  16  26  46  10  20  50  40  25  15
A2  24  18  24  26  20  20  20  20  25  25
A3  48  15  30  18  30  10  10  10  20  45
A4  16  51  20  10  40  50  20  30  30  15
```

I wish the data should be visible only for latest six months. for example, if the current month for Oct-13,

```
ID  Apr-13  May-13  Jun-13  Jul-13  Aug-13  Sep-13
A1  10  20  50  40  25  15
A2  20  20  20  20  25  25
A3  30  10  10  10  20  45
A4  40  50  20  30  30  15
```

If the current month is Nov-13, the values for Oct-13 will be visible.

```
ID  May-13  Jun-13  Jul-13  Aug-13  Sep-13  Oct-13
A1  20  50  40  25  15  10
A2  20  20  20  25  25  25
A3  10  10  10  20  45  35
A4  50  20  30  30  15  30
```

The remaining columns should be hidden. If there is no data in Oct-13 the current month view should be same as Sep-13. I have month row is filled till 2014 and each row has formula based on another sheet "Sheet2". If I add data for oct-13 in "Sheet2", the data will be visible for Oct-13 column in "Sheet1" otherwise it will be blank. It will be helpful if someone help me how to make this dynamic using excel VBA.

Assuming my header is in row 2 and I am picking up the current date using the `today()` function.  I am checking the current date with the month mentioned in the same column.  today() function is to be moved to next cell when there are values in that column.  otherwise it remains in the same column.  Here is my workaround for the above task. I think this needs to be simplified and working.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Cells(A1).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    r = Selection.Row
    c = Selection.Column
    If Month(Cells(r, c)) = Month(Cells(r + 1, c)) + 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Select
        Range(Selection, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)).Select
        Selection.Hide
        Cells(r, c).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Selection.End(xlToRight).Select)).Select
        Selection.Hide
    Else
        Cells(r, c).Content.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Is my question not clear

Comment: You haven't shown a evidence of an attempted solution.

Comment: expected result is being given and also my attempt was provided.  Please help me to fix it.